# Biconvex Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

A function $f(x, y): B\to R$ is called a biconvex function if fixing $x$, $f_x(y)=f(x, y)$ is convex over **$Y$** and fixing $y$, $f_y(x)=f(x, y)$ is convex over **$X$**. $B$ is a biconvex set that is, $B \subset X\times Y$ if for every fixed $y \in Y$, $B_y= \{x\in X: (x, y)\in B\}$ is a convex set in $X$ and for every fixed $x \in X$, $B_x= \{y\in Y: (x, y)\in B\}$ is a convex set in $Y$. I am trying to understand this class of functions, looking for interesting functions that fall in this category and Optimization methods.

**My Understanding:**
I know that convex function has this property that they are convex on all lines passing through the domain. We can tell similar things for Biconvex Functions, that they are convex on all lines parallel to Axes and passing through the domain.

From the above definition, we can construct functions which have many local minima along lines not parallel to Axes. In such a scenario is it even possible to reach a global minima? If yes can you please give an intuitive idea to do that?

Comment: There are too many "ifs" in this question for me to understand it properly.  The function  $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is biconvex, so I suppose you want to know which if its "properties" hold for all biconvex functions?

Comment: @kimchilover I am sorry, I did not mean that. By parallel to Axes, I meant Horizontal and Vertical Lines for 2-D functions. Can you please help me to edit this?

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly. Can you please let me know if any more clarity is needed?

Comment: What are you assuming about $B$ ? If $B=[-1,1]^2$, and if $f(x,y)=xy$, when restricted to  the line cut out by $x+y=0$ you have multiple local minima.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, you are correct there are two minimas to be precise, function value goes to $-1$ at those points. I have edited the question to define $B$. Thanks for the suggestion.